# Удаление знаков в цепочке

Tags: c, строки, функции

```
#include <stdio.h>
int prumer(char pole[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (pole[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return i;
}

int substring_delete(char input[], char start[], char end[]) {
    int i, j;
    int counter = 0;
    int start_pos = 0;
    int end_pos = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < prumer(input); i++) {
        if (input[i] == start[0]) {
            counter = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < prumer(start); j++) {
                if (input[i + j] == start[j]) {
                    counter++;
                    if (j == (prumer(start) - 1)) {
                        start_pos = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < prumer(input); i++) {
        if (input[i] == end[0]) {
            counter = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < prumer(end); j++) {
                if (input[i + j] == end[j]) {
                    counter++;
                    if (j == (prumer(end) - 1)) {
                        end_pos = (i + j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int replace_counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (prumer(input) - 1); i++) {
        if (i >= start_pos && i <= end_pos) {
            input[i] = '*';
            replace_counter++;
        }
    }
    return replace_counter;
}

int main()
{
    char input[] = "b/*bce*/a";
    int sub = substring_delete(input, "/*", "*/");
    printf("%d", sub);
    printf("%s", input);
    getch();
}
```

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема. Это код, который удаляет (должен) все знаки от start до end. Проблема заключается в том, что она не удаляет, а замещает на другой какой-то знак. Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, решение? (нам запретили использовать любые библиотеки, только для проверки в main можно использовать stdio.h)

Answer (score 0):

Последний цикл:

```
int replace_counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < (prumer(input) - 1); i++) {
        if (i >= start_pos && i <= end_pos) {
            input[i] = '*';
            replace_counter++;
        }
    }
```

меняете так :

```
int replace_counter = end_pos + 1 - start_pos;
j = end_pos + 1 ;
for (i = start_pos; j < prumer(input) + 1 ; i++,++j)  input[i] = input[j];
```

Два индекса **i** и **j** берёте и перекидываете буквы.

Ошибки желательно исправить: отсутствие слова `start` - ничего не делать. И отсутствие слова `end` - ничего не удалять. После перемещения букв нужно заново стартануть функцию , пройтись ещё раз. (Их может быть  много `/*x*//*y*/` )